# ImGui, how to get value that the mouse is pointing at in a VSliderFloat widget

Tags: c++, imgui

I am using ImGui::VSliderFloat to create a vertical slider in the GUI of my application. To do this I just copied the imgui demo code (imgui_demo.cpp), which reads something like

`ImGui::VSliderFloat("##v", ImVec2(18,160), &values[i], 0.0f, 1.0f, "");
                if (ImGui::IsItemActive() || ImGui::IsItemHovered())
                    ImGui::SetTooltip("%.3f", values[i]);`

In the demo they have stored some values in the array values[7]. My question is about the tooltip. When you point your mouse at the VSlider, the tooltip you get is the current value in values[i]. Is there some way I that I could ask ImGui for the value of the slider that the mouse is pointing at?

Comment: Why just that value? What do you want to accomplish?

Comment: I would just like to get the value that the user is pointing to, in order to render a preview of the data in small. As an example, imagine the VSlider is a scrollbar. I would like to render in a small frame the screen to where the user would scroll to in case he/she clicks the VSlider. Other examples could be thought of too.